# Why is the resistivity of a copper cable much higher than copper?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

I was looking at the data sheet for a copper cable and noticed the conductor resistance to be specified at around 5 mOhm/m. This is magnitudes higher than pure copper, which has a resistance in the order of 10 nOhm*m (from Wikipedia). Why is the resistivity so much higher?

Comment: Watch out not to confuse *resistance* and *resistivity* in your question. By the way, what is your source for those numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resistivity of a metal gives the resistance it will have based on the cross-sectional area and the length of the conductor.

$$ \rho = \frac {AR}{L} $$

This means that resitivity is in SI units of $\Omega\text{ m}$.  Neither of your quoted figures are in such units.  Copper has a resistivity around $1.68 \times 10^{-8} \Omega \text{ m}$.

Unlike the bulk metal, a wire or conductor is manufactured with a constant cross section.  If you pull the cross section away, you can characterize it with resistance per length, or $\frac{\Omega}{\text{m}}$.

In fact, assuming the wire above is copper, we can calculate the size based on linear resistance figure given.

$$\rho = \frac{AR}{L}$$
$$A = \frac{\rho} {\frac{R}{L}}$$
$$A = \frac{1.68 \times 10^{-8}\Omega \text{ m}}{5 \times 10^{-3}\Omega \text{ m}^{-1}}$$
$$A = 3.36\times 10^{-6}\text{m}^2 = 3.36\text{mm}^2$$

That cross section happens to be quite close to that of 12 gauge (AWG) wire.

Comment: I had noted the wrong unit for pure copper, but you got it all right in your answer :)